# Export data and SFTP

Tags: java, sftp

I am looking for a best way to export data from Oracle Database and SFTP files using Java.

Any framework that does things out of box? Spring Modules?

Comment: Finally, I have used Spring Batch and Integrated it with Spring Integration framework!

Comment: Split them up - data export from Oracle and sftp'ing are orthogonal tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have used Spring Batch and Integrated it with Spring Integration framework!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [Spring Batch](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?104574-SFTP-and-Spring-Batch-integration) can help you.

Answer (score 1):

We use [JScape](http://www.jscape.com/) for our Java SFTP needs. Costs $$$ but has been reliable.

Answer (score 1):

We use JSch from [JCraft](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) which is a free pure Java implementation of SSH2.  It works really well.

Here's a good link with a sftp example using JSch:

> http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sftp.java